# Mapped lookup in excel without duplication

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very somewhat complicated question (at least to me ) and I'm hoping someone will be kind enough to help. I hope my explanation is good enough

I have a mapping table like below, we have multiple elements b mapped to element a

```
| Element a     |Element b|
|---------------|-------- | 
| B10           | 212010  |
| B101          | 212010  |
| B102          | 212010  |
| B103          | 212010  |
| B104          | 212010  |
| B301          | 111030  |
| B302          | 111030  |
| B303          | 111030  |
| B304          | 111030  |
|---------------|-------- |
```

Each element in the above table will have a value in another table:

```
| Element A |    Value    |
|-----------|-------------|
| B10       |  1,000.00   |
| B101      |  2,000.00   |
| B102      |  6,000.00   |
| B103      |  1,000.00   |
| B104      |  10,000.00  |
| B301      |  1,000.00   |
| B302      |  2,000.00   |
| B303      |  6,000.00   |
| B304      |  1,000.00   |
|-----------|-------------|


| Element B |    Value    |
|-----------|-------------|
|    212010 |  20,000.00  |
|    111030 |  10,000.00  |
|-----------|-------------|
```

I have to compare the value of the corresponding elements above using the mapping table, I'm looking for a solution that looks like the table below -

[image: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/--vkiEh3uf4M/UoXR_KRXU_I/AAAAAAAD1CY/eMFagcBpwtY/s800/snip.PNG]

Steps:

1. Compare the value of each element side by side without duplicating element b
2. if possible put a box around each mapped element and value

I understand it may only be possible to the above using only VBA macros, but a similar solution using only excel formula will be very appreciated.

The solution should be compatible with Excel 2003.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a column after element a and insert formula:

=VLOOKUP(A2;$F$2:$G$7;2;FALSE)

$F$2:$G$7 should refer to the sheet/range of your values

the column after element b should contain the formula:
=IF(C2<>C1;VLOOKUP(C2;$F$2:$G$7;2;FALSE);"")

Then put a conditional format in for the border based on the cell in d column being empty or not.
Go to conditional formating and select "use formula"
type in formula:
$D2<>""

And select the tab border to select top border.

Comment: Hi @robbert-koppenol thanks, this works where column C is sorted, would you have a formula for me where C is unsorted? Also I want the grouping done by 'where element B are the same', not where cell D is empty. I will mark yours as accepted if I see no improved answer since I can still use it to achieve something similar. Thank you once again

Comment: No, you need sort first on column c (and add a secondary sort level on A if you like it to be neat). Seems it was done already but OK. See I do not order on column D, I just used the fact that column "element B" IS ordered. Only the first value of a "value-block" in the element B column  will by means of the if-statement get a value. So every value in column D indicates a new equal-value block in column "element B".

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by sql query in excel if you have these tables in different sheets you can join them.

In sql after select statement you can type Distinct and this will delete the duplicates.